# I have to select a specific row in an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, xml, closedxml

I'm working on an Excel file that I have to convert to an XML file.
Every time I cycle the rows to check if they are empty I use this code:

```
var ComuniRow = firstRowUsed.RowUsed();
while (!ComuniRow.Cell(coComuneId).IsEmpty())
{
    // do stuff;
}
```

This time tho I need to select a specific row, not the starting one but I have no Idea about how to do that.
Any solutions?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the rows.

```
public void UngroupFromAll(){
 IXLWorksheet ws = new XLWorkbook().AddWorksheet("Sheet1");
 ws.Rows(1, 2).Group();
 ws.Rows(1, 2).Ungroup(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Indrit, I was going to reply to my own answer because I just found it out.
Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Great! :) 
For more examples, you can check this page: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/ClosedXML.Excel/XLWorkbook/Row/php-xlworkbook-row-method-examples.html